# VC++ listbox to listbox

Tags: winforms, listbox, c++-cli, managed-c++, listbox-control

I'm using VC++ and 2 listboxs, i need to transfer the items from the first listbox to the second.
i used this code but it only transfer the 1st item repeated as much as the first listbox contains items (the items count) :

```
for (int x = 0; x < Listbox1->Items->Count; x++)
 {
    Listbox1->SetSelected(x, true);
    String^ curItem = Listbox1->SelectedItem->ToString();
    listBox2->Items->Add(curItem);
    std::string str = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(curItem);
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(str, 1);
    cv::imshow("ShowImage", img);
    cvWaitKey(5000);
 }
```

I have to do an auto-selection of the items